# Logistic Regression with R and Hadoop

Tags: r, hadoop, linear-regression

We are using `rmr` and `rhadoop package` of `RevoR`. Can we perform linear regression on an entire data set in hadoop without the need to implement the linear regression algorithm in map reduce

or

Is rmr and rhadoop, just used for summarizing the data and then running regression on the summarized data locally?

Answer (score 0):

Neither. You can implement any sort of algorithm in rmr, not only summaries. However, it's not an algorithm package, as such it doesn't include linear regression or clustering or anything of that sort, much like packages parallel or snow.

Comment: Thanks. So we basically need to manually write code to fit the regression model? For example, compute mean, compute cost function, apply gradient descent etc etc?

Comment: I think so. There may be certain problems where one can just compute independent solutions in the  mapper and then merge them in the reduce phase. One example  of this approach working is the function max: take the max of arbitrary subsets, then the max of the maxes. For the mean, one can do the mean of means as long as they are properly weighted. For linear regression, I am not sure.